# Change app-wide thematic color at runtime

Tags: android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

I have an application with an color that is used throughout the app as an accent color.  It's used for selected drop-downs, some headings, some buttons, to tint images, etc etc.  I would like the user to be able to pick this color the in the applications settings and have it update throughout the app immediately when the setting is changed.

How do I go about doing this?

The senior developer who started this project defined the following in the `Attrs.xml` file:

```
<declare-styleable name="AirWare.Theme">
  <attr name="primaryAccentColor" format="reference|color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

...And everywhere we reference the color, be it from Styles.xml or within individual drawables and layout files, we reference it as `?attr/primaryAccentColor`.  He says he read that this could be updated at runtime programmatically, but he can't find or remember the code he used to test that out.  He's moved on to other projects.  Is this the starting point to a solution for our need?

We are targeting Android Lolipop / API21 / 5.0.  We are also using Xamarin, but any solution in Java is fine; I can translate to C#/Xamarin APIs without a problem.